# Fill a part of a vector with randomly generated values in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to write a Sequential Monte Carlo function in Rcpp, and I having the following problem:

I have created a vector the following way:

```
  NumericVector R_t(Part*Ttau);
```

and I want to fill ONLY Part blocks of the vector. It should be like:

```
for (int i=0;i<Part;i++){
        R_t[i]=runif(1,0,2);
}
```

and the second time I'd like to have

```
for (int i=Part+1;i<2*Part;i++){
            R_t[i]=runif(1,0,2);
}
```

But it does not seem to work. I could replace the old values with the new ones in each iteration, but I need the old ones for each iteration. When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
cannot convert 'Rcpp::NUmericVector {aka Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PrserveStorage>}' to 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>:: type {aka double}' in assignment
```

Would it be easier to replace the vector with a 2-d matrix with dimensions Part and Ttau? I would like to avoid this last option.

Sorry if this has been answered, but I did not find anything close to this for rcpp

Comment: Since you, already, allocate `Part * Ttau` space, why not use a "matrix" and in each 'Ttau' iteration fill the respective column like `for(int i = 0; i < Ttau; i++) for(int j = 0; j < Part; j++) R_t[i + j*Part] = runif()`?

Comment: That would be nice, but unfortunately, it's not my code and I have to write to Rcpp, and the code I have is in this format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to assign a length-one vector to a location that expects a `double`, so use `[0]` to access the first element: `runif(1,0,2)[0]`. However, you can also just replace your loop with Rcpp sugar constructs to avoid repeatedly generating one random value at a time:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fill_vector(R_xlen_t n, R_xlen_t m) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector res(n);
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        res[i] = Rcpp::runif(1, 0, 2)[0];
    }
    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fill_vector2(R_xlen_t n, R_xlen_t m) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector res(n);
    res[Rcpp::seq(0, m - 1)] = Rcpp::runif(m, 0, 2);
    return res;
}

/***R

set.seed(123)
fill_vector(7, 4)
#[1] 0.5751550 1.5766103 0.8179538 1.7660348 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

set.seed(123)
fill_vector2(7, 4)
#[1] 0.5751550 1.5766103 0.8179538 1.7660348 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

set.seed(123)
c(runif(4, 0, 2), rep(0, 3))
#[1] 0.5751550 1.5766103 0.8179538 1.7660348 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could that be the same for a function like dbinom in R?

Comment: `std::generate(res.begin(), res.begin() + m, unif_rand);` also works.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options when it comes to RNGs:

1. Use [Rcpp sugar](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) to match `runif(n,a,b)` in R via `Rcpp::runif(n,a,b)` (returns `NumericVector` or
2. Create your own loop to mimic `runif(n,a,b)` by drawing each time from `R::runif(a,b)`

@nrussell demoed how to use 1 by subsetting the vector via `Rcpp::runif(n,a,b)[0]` but left out approach 2.

Below is how to go about approach 2:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector draw_vector(int n, int m) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector res(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    res[i] = R::runif(0.0, 2.0); // Draw a single element that is a double
  }
  return res;
}

/***R
set.seed(123)
draw_vector(7, 4)
*/
```

This gives:

```
[1] 0.5751550 1.5766103 0.8179538 1.7660348 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Could that work for more complicated functions eg the equivalent of dbinom in R?

Comment: Yes. Just note the parameter structure of `?dbinom`. You will need to call with `double` and `bool`.